# MongoDB Authentication (user won't change)

Tags: authentication, mongodb

I am trying to authenticate myself as a different user from the Mongo shell. Even though I am told the authentication worked, the actual user won't change. I only seem to have this error for some user accounts and not all though, as shown in the image below.

[image: MongoDB Error Pic]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you expecting will change based on successful or unsuccessful auth? What are your specific shell and server versions as reported by `version()` and `db.version()`? Logging in as a new user does not automatically logout any previous users in the current session (use `db.logout()` for this). There are use cases where you may need to combine user permissions (for example, reading from one database and writing to another) where a single user in your environment does not have all required privileges. To see current auth'd users in the `mongo` shell: `db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1}).`

Comment: I think this part below answers my question

       _Logging in as a new user does not automatically logout any previous 
         users in the current session_

I thought if you authorized yourself as a new user, it would log you out of the previous users. I didn't realize that you can combine user permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging in as a new user does not automatically logout any previous users in the current session (use `db.logout()` for this).

There are some use cases where you may need to combine user permissions (for example, reading from one database and writing to another) where a single user in your environment does not have all required privileges. This is a somewhat legacy carryover from older versions of MongoDB (2.2 and earlier) that had more simplistic per-database authentication without [custom roles and privileges](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/).

To see current authenticated users in the current `mongo` shell session, use `db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})`.

Comment: So do you know the logic for how user permissions are combined? Why is it that some users get logged out when I authorize myself with a new user and some users are not logged out?

So in my example, the user _user_ was only logged out when I authorized myself as the _dba_ user, but when I authorized myself as the _testRead_ user, it just combined those permissions with the _user_ permissions

Comment: The permissions should be additive if you are logging into the same session. How are you confirming the user is logged out? Also, what are your versions of MongoDB shell & server as reported by `version()` and `db.version()`? I would confirm logged-in users via `connectionStatus`; your shell prompt only appears to show one user.

Comment: I am using Mongo 3.6.1......And based on my example above, I can confirm that if I authorize myself first as _user_ and then authorize myself as _testRead_, it will add those permissions and when I run `connectionStatus`, it shows both users. But when I authorize myself as _dba_, it replaces _user_, and `connectionStatus` shows only _dba_ and _testRead_